# how to know if new version of my app is showing ads?

Tags: android, firebase, admob, ads

I released an update of an app of mine on the play store (gradual implementation) but I suspect ads are not working anymore because I added a rewarded ad and I'm not receiving impressions from that even if some users have upgraded by now. My fear is that since I changed the implementation of the ads, the banner and the interstitial are also affected by this issue. Is there an option in dev console, admob, firebase, or analytics that will show the version of the app the impression is generated from so I can check if the new version is generating impressions before I update the gradual implementation?

Comment: I have no idea tbh, but just out of curiosity, a maybe stupid question: Why can't you test it on a device yourself?

Comment: On my testing device it works but not on the emulator, hence my suspects..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- when u upload a new update on the play store ... this does not mean every one will get it when the new version is live, u need to give users time to update to the new version, so it is best leave your banner and old ads with the new for some time so that u don't loss revenue.

2- go to "firebase" then "Analytics Dashboard" go down to "[Event count by Event name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUTYr.png)" then select "ad_impression" click on "[All Users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOBqV.png)" and on the right change "audience name" to "[App Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uExql.png)"

hope this helped ... good luck ❤️.

Comment: thank you, that's what I was looking for. I have also old ads on the new version and it does show that I'm getting impressions from those ones at least. Anyway I tried to ask the same question to chatgpt while I was waiting for responses and it did find the answer. It was faster but it didn't send me a heart lol :) thanks!